# Demonstrated through?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Is this sentence correct?
"Excellent communication, organizational, and leadership skills demonstrated through various awards and volunteer activities."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You seem to be unfamiliar with Stack Exchange; I encourage you to visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) and take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) for guidance on how to use these sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a résumé bullet point; it seems OK to me in that context.

However, if I was to nit-pick, I would say that while one can demonstrate one's skills through activities, skills are not demonstrated through awards; rather, awards *acknowledge* or *recognize* skills that have been *demonstrated* through activities.